# 401 Error on Blackberry Device

Tags: 2010, blackberry

I have a SharePoint instance serving as our Extranet to our salesforce.  All sales agents have a Blackberry device, but none can access our Extranet.

In IIS, we only have ASP.NET Impersonation and Windows Authentication enabled, but the BB device doesnt even prompt for credentials, it just receives a 401 error.

Needless to say, the site is browsable on other devices (PC, tablet, iPhone..), so it seems to be something specific to BB settings - or thats my inclination.  Anyone have any thoughts on how I can troubleshoot\resolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, found the answer. Blackberry doesnt support Windows Authentication since the browser is too old. I had to turn on Basic Authentication, which isnt recommended unless your running over SSL.. which fortunately I am. Found the answer here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907273

Answer (score 0):

first, on IIS, authentication you should to have enabled BASIC AUTHENTICATION, then in the Sharepoint Central Administration go to App managment, then Manage applications.

Now you select your website for example (Sharepoint - 80), then you click on Authentication Providers.

Now.. in the zone you select DEFAULT, then enable "anonymous access" and Basic Authentication.

Enjoy.